# How to change the markup for a field

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I'd like to change the output from the field formatter view from the Field API. I'd like a cleaner markup without unnecessary tags. What's the best way to clean up field formatter view output? Many thanks.

Ideally to change from this:

```
<div class="field field--name-field-visualisation field--type-mango-maker field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Visualisation:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field__items">
        <div class="field__item even">
            <div class="something"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="field field--name-field-visualisation field--type-mango-maker field--label-above">
    <div class="field__label">Visualisation:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="something"></div>
</div>
```

heres my hook_function_field_formatter_view function:

```
function mango_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {

  $output[0] = array(
    '#theme' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('something'),
    ),
  );
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change output of the field in a Views, use [Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews)

You can also turn on the Theme Developer module, check which .tpl is used to display piece of content you want to change and then create this file in a way you want.

Another modules that provide similar functionalities are:

Quickest solution, just turn this module and forget about drupal's nested divs:

[Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences)

More complex, this lets you to set up fields markup - for views as well as full node:

[Semantic CCK](https://www.drupal.org/project/semantic_cck)

The most complex, apart from fields markup, this lets you to set up columns, headers, footers etc. inside of full node view, as well some views integration:

[Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)

Answer (score 0):

I recently came to this same obstacle and managed to find a solution. @15dk51 did an excellent job of explaining the answer to this.

[Removing divs added by render and node.tpl.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6069/removing-divs-added-by-render-and-node-tpl-php)

Best solution I found was installing [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) which has effectively removed allot of the "drupal rendered" css classes which seem unnecessary when building your own theme.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I always lean to templates when I can. Using templates is a great way to control the markup of your fields or other elements in a Drupal friendly way.

More than likely you would be looking at creating a file called "field--name-field-visualisation.tpl.php" or whatever your field name is.

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7.x

Couple things to help when using .tpl template files... Depending on your site configuration, you may have to add theme hook suggestions to "$variables" in your theme file. Also, kpr() or dpm() is your magic for finding what's available how to print it in your template file.

Don't forget to clear cache when you create a new template file!

Related reading: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There are two crucial guides I'd like to warmly recommend to you: [Core templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/core-templates) and [Template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions).

You want to completely customize the markup of one field. Then you need to find your current theme's or base theme's `field.tpl.php` file and duplicate that into your theme's `/templates` folder. Then you can rename it along the following patterns (choose one) to selectively customize the output for only one desired field (instead of overriding markup globally for all fields):

```
field--FIELD-NAME--NODE-TYPE.tpl.php
field--NODE-TYPE.tpl.php
field--FIELD-NAME.tpl.php
field--FIELD-TYPE.tpl.php
```

---

Additionally (and this only is an extra step after you tried to tweak things with the above options) you can also provide your own custom field formatter to fine-tune the field value output even more.

See the answers to [How do I write an additional field formatter for an existing field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/79561/15055), which will tell you to implement `hook_field_formatter_info()` and `hook_field_formatter_view()`, both.